# Return a list of names who are members of multiple groups, the data feed is differing from a previous question

Tags: python

The Employee class has attributes set and I need to return a list from a data feed.

### employee.py

```
class Employee(object):

    def __init__(self, id, name, members=None):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.members = members
        self.is_team = members is not None
```

Employee's can be members of more than one group.

### feed.py

```
from employee import Employee

anne = Employee(0, 'Anne')
bob = Employee(1, 'Bob')
carlos = Employee(2, 'Carlos')
carol = Employee(3, 'Carol')
charlie = Employee(4, 'Charlie')
cherry = Employee(5, 'Cherry')
dave = Employee(6, 'Dave')
emma = Employee(7, 'Emma')
mary = Employee(8, 'Mary')
peggy = Employee(9, 'Peggy')
trent = Employee(10, 'Trent')

admin = Employee(90, 'Admin', [anne, bob, carlos])
engineering = Employee(91, 'Engineering', [carlos, peggy, trent])
catering = Employee(92, 'Catering', [admin, charlie, mary])

people = [anne, bob, carlos, carol, charlie, cherry, dave, emma, 
mary, peggy, trent, admin, engineering, catering]
```

My solution.

```
import feed


def get_names(person, p_list):
    try:
        for p in p_list:
            all_members = p.members
            if all_members and person in all_members:
                yield p
    except AttributeError:
        print('Not found')


print([t.name for t in get_names(feed.anne, feed.people)])
```

The data returned should be:

```
['Admin', 'Catering']
```

As anne belongs to both groups, she is admin and also part of catering.

Comment: So where is your problem? Doesn't this solution work?

Comment: `anne` is not part of `catering` in your example, but `admin` is. Is it a typo?

Comment: I think you should flattening `admin` in `catering` or any group has `admin` before checking. `catering` should be `[anne, bob, carlos, charlie, mary] `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I have an Employee class which i would like to return a List of 'names'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57987959/i-have-an-employee-class-which-i-would-like-to-return-a-list-of-names)

Comment: @jinksy The data feed differs from the possible duplicate and requires a different solution. shubham has provided the correct solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this function instead of yours:

```
def get_names(person, p_list):
    try:
        for p in p_list:
            all_members = p.members
            if all_members is not None:
                if person in all_members:
                    yield p
                for i in all_members:
                    if i.members is not None:
                        temp = i.members
                        if person in temp:
                            yield p
    except AttributeError:
        print('Not found')
```

Comment: What if we also have the branches of anne? It means if we have more than 2 levels, Does your solution work?

Comment: it will not work in 2 level branches, it will only work in 1 level

Answer (score 0):

I would distinguish Role from an Employee and create separate classes for both as they represent different business logic.

```
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name, groups):
        self.name = name
        self.groups = []
        for group in groups:
            self.add_group(group)
    def add_group(self, group):
        if not group in self.groups:
            self.groups.append(group)
            group.add_member(self)
    def in_multiple_groups(self):
        return len(self.groups) > 1

class Role(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.members = []
    def add_member(self, employee):
        if not employee in self.employees:
            self.employees.append(employee)
            employee.add_group(self)
```

So now finding employees with multiple groups is a lot easier

```
admin = Role('admin')
engineering = Role('engineering')

alice = Employee(0, 'Alice', [admin])
bob = Employee(1, 'Bob', [admin, engineering])
tom = Employee(2, 'Tom', [admin, engineering])

employees = [alice, bob, tom]

for employee in employees:
    if employee.in_multiple_groups():
        //do something
```